# JavaScript if check-box is checked not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, required

I have a website form where I have fields that I want to be required (with JQuery Plugin) only when the check-box is checked.

So far I wrote JavaScript that works if the the check-box is not checked, or checked. But when a user checks the check-box and then unchecks it the code does not work (field is still mandatory when unchecked).

Also one other bug is for some reason this same code only works for updating only one items required boolean. For example if I have the same code but make it so two elements requirements are updated the script does not work at all.

Here is the relevant source code:

```
<script>
function swap(){
  if(document.getElementById('must').checked){     
    document.getElementById("element1").setAttribute("required", "true");
  }else{      
    document.getElementById("element1").setAttribute("required", "false");
  }
}
</script>


<form>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="swap();" id="must" name="must" value="1" style="width:10;">
<input id="element1" type="text" name="element1" placeholder="Enter Value" >
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" >
</form>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in xhtml we specify required="required" and there no required="false", a better way is to remove attribute required on else

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function swap(){
  if(document.getElementById('must').checked){     
    document.getElementById("element1").setAttribute("required", "required");
  }else{      
    document.getElementById("element1").removeAttribute("required");
  }
}
    </script>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! Apparently setting the required attribute to another value did not work and you were right, I had to remove that element attribute. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Best way I know to check if `checkbox` is `checked`, it to use jQuery `is()` method ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/is/)). It handles x-browser differences for you. Also best way to add attribute to HTML element is to use `attr()` method.

```
if($("#must").is(":checked")) {
    $("#element1").attr('required', 'required');
} else {
    $("#element1").removeAttr();
}
```

You can check in DOM inspector that attribute is added.

Required attribute documentation is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute).

Comment: I tried that but got the same result; could it be due to required="false" not really making the element required. If I remember correctly in the past when I added required="false" on an element it still was required.

Comment: @Carlos the problem isn't his method of checking if it's checked

Comment: I've just noticed what was the problem, but @DevonBernard was faster;)

Comment: @Carlos: Either way I appreciate your help. I thought that the required attribute had to be set as true to work but apparently I was wrong, I will make sure the next time I have a similar bug to see if I need to remove the attribute instead. Thanks again +1.

Answer (score 0):

The required attribute is a boolean attribute, it presence means that the field is required and its absence means the field isn't required. It has only 3 valid forms  1. `required` alone by itself 2. `required=""` equal to an empty string 3. `required="required"`